# Determine type of property from other property

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Inside of a class, I know that a property will be one of a discriminated union based on another property, but I can't figure out how to get TypeScript to reflect that.

I've tried extending a discriminated union such as the following, but that doesn't work.

```js
type A = { thing: 1, otherThing: string }
type B = { thing: 2, otherThing: number }
type C = A | B;

// ERROR: A class can only implement an object type or intersection
// of object types with statically known members. ts(2422)
class C implements C {
  // ...
}
```

The method works, but this question is to see if I can make it work with a getter instead of a method.

```js
class Example {
  thing: 1 | 2;

  get otherThing() {
    if (this.thing === 1) return 'one';
    return 2;
  }

  getOtherThing(thing: 1): string;
  getOtherThing(thing: 2): number;
  getOtherThing(): string | number {
    if (this.thing === 1) return 'one';
    return 2;
  }

  constructor(value: Example['thing']) {
    this.thing = value;
  }

  fails() {
    // I'd really like this type of logic to work
    if (this.thing === 1) {
      // Type '2 | "one"' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      const test: string = this.otherThing;
    }
  }

  works() {
    if (this.thing === 1) {
      const test: string = this.getOtherThing(this.thing);
    }
  }
}
```

> Edit: Specifically this issue is for use within the same class. The [solution provided by @jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58104899/5175115) is excellent, and if what I'm seeking cannot be done, then I could use that solution with composition in order to achieve similar results.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is covered in the official [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) from Microsoft.

Comment: @JaredSmith that handbook does in fact cover discriminated unions, but it does not cover how to make classes have fields with types that interact within the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single class or interface can't extend or implement a union of things, so it isn't possible to achieve what you want directly.  If you really need a single class to give you behavior like a discriminated union, I would think about using a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) class in which your dependent property is of a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types):

```
class Example<T extends C["thing"]> {
  constructor(
    public thing: T,
    public otherThing: Extract<C, { thing: T }>["otherThing"]
  ) {}
}
```

In the specific instance where the discriminant property `thing` is a valid key type (and `1 | 2` works), you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) instead of conditional types (although I'll make the mapping out of a conditional type like this):

```
type MappedOtherThing = {
  [K in C["thing"]]: Extract<C, { thing: K }>["otherThing"]
};

class Example<T extends C["thing"]> {
  constructor(public thing: T, public otherThing: MappedOtherThing[T]) {}
}
```

The `Extract<C, {thing: T}>["otherThing"]` uses the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) utility type to find the member of `C` which is assignable to `{thing: T}`, and then [looks up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) its `otherThing` property.

Either of those implementations will give you this behavior:

```
const eA = new Example(1, "okay"); // Example<1>
eA.otherThing; // string
const a: A = eA; // okay
const eB = new Example(2, 12345); // Example<2>
eB.otherThing; // number
const b: B = eB; // okay
const c: C = Math.random() < 0.5 ? eA : eB; // okay
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#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-iQQTVVHT5eDoYA8om7NHOvkANJIHioIolXjlMqCJam5prDYx-uCLu7fYttTHLxaWtecKRaLxGGpdKZbK5XvFI6VcNdMJ4xrNVptKb9QZTkYbG8zNEFwQNiCYZv5uz5WRlM6kFcNA+queKunSbyboy3y-Eg-zkqCpJQUK8KIiiL52KSKa8FqBJEsYSKepqoFUqqxjPJBHxfMyrIcjyfICshsIioiBgSt+GL8lCRbyiRirKgRapcWSxG1GBOoVgaRqcCaZqYBaVpIDa9qOi6SJuqqREUpQVxAA)

Comment: That is a great solution.

However, it doesn't seem to work inside the class, which is my goal. I will see if I can edit the original question to include that.

Comment: Do you think it would be safe to say that what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "inside the class" or "within the same class".  Can you elaborate on what is insufficient about the `Example` class implementation I gave here?

Comment: I mean, is [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVgAsCWA7A5gLigEYBuKAe3QgCcAVTXAgZ2CuxygF9iBYAKFEhQAQgmSp6+KACZSFNNTpsCWAK4BbAEbVOPfuGgBhUXAA+w3XwHQAsgEMwkACYB5SrQmikfKFADaAaShsKANfACJ0NjCAXWiCAFEADxZbAGNgAB4DABoxSIYoQI4APnC5BQkYvi4+PlSAG1tGRigk2zUweogMmigIZIgsRxbQiMro4uRvKFSyLGYqFXSyKgAKMBUNeoxU8SUoGgBKZA5a3h8cCGByN0VcVeOvc58ZueYoNXsnV3l3fbsHBAXLcPIgUIQCGE5hAwrkpAQpDppj4qFcVFQsB8vkCfhU2L5IowAHT5HDRXQ+U68Kl1N7XCBwRBYCAAd1aiXanQgq0Ih1IAHp+ezOV0MoRirT5tdbARGX0YAKhWQANa2ECS94QERM1nCjpdVZSPlQQV6rkZKQS3izKVQDQEbV9ISK8iq9W8IA) what you want?  It's basically the same. 

Comment: I've [added a function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVgAsCWA7A5gLigEYBuKAe3QgCcAVTXAgZ2CuxygF9iBYAKFEhQAQgmSp6+KACZSFNNTpsCWAK4BbAEbVOPfuGgBhUXAA+w3XwHQAsgEMwkACYB5SrQmikfKFADaAaShsKANfACJ0NjCAXWiCAFEADxZbAGNgAB4DABoxSIYoQI4APnC5BQkYvi4+PlSAG1tGRigk2zUweogMmigIZIgsRxbQiMro4uRvKFSyLGYqFXSyKgAKMBUNeoxU8SUoGgBKZA5a3h8cCGByN0VcVeOvc58ZueYoNXsnV3l3fbsHBAXLcPIgUIQCGE5hAwrkpAQpDozi8oFQrioqFgPl8gT8KmxfJFGAA6fI4aK6HynXjTYAQZgPKbPHwYABmUFWRNJoPgiEIj2mKNm82utiYLDYoi55T+uEpL2pgqC7M5mBJZIQvOkAuZL2F7w0ynUWioUrVxJldxwSpqz2p1KAA) `test()` to show where my problem lies.

Comment: That is a mostly separate [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) having to do with trying to narrow a generic extending a union; for now the way you deal with it is to do the narrowing yourself with a [type assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgogD2AWwAdkBTAHgBUFjsJiA7AEwwEYEAfBAJgD4EBvALAAoBAlCQY8BBAAWASzoBzAFwJyAbmGjx0OIgD2s4lHLylqvgmaqJCxeq6q6AVzwhjCAL4BtcgF1NEWliSAAKAEp+LVEEOQAzBFDZOTAAOmSlBABeHKtIwSCYpH06SDEbaDtsxOSMNCxcQhJSZm5w1MMZY1M7QKLPaNF4mvk0jMVs3M58wZjYErKQJ1d3KGqk0bEMHHwiMh52zu6zCfqXN2M+mIGgm5ugA).

Comment: Thank you very much, @jcalz. This helps me better understand what needs to be done.